# Updating datastore entities with appcfg.py renames primary key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using appcfg.py to update the entities in my datastore.  I upload a csv:

```
Name,Type
Jim,2
Bob,4
```

I then look in the datastore and note that the primary key field for these entities are of the form "**id=#**". I then download this datastore type using appcfg.py, it comes down as:

```
Name,Type,id
Jim,2,10001
Bob,4,10002
```

I modify the Type field and upload it again.  The result is a duplicate set of entries where now the primary key is of the form "**name=#**".  Looking through my config.yaml, this is the relevant entry for the key:

```
 property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: id
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

I simply want to update the existing datastore entities, how do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
- property: __key__ 
  external_name: key 
  export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string 
  import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('YourKind', key_is_id=True)
```

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/3f211d42cf544c1a/4659a30b9380ab8a?lnk=gst&q=key_id_or_name_as_string#4659a30b9380ab8a

Comment: This was the solution.  However, it should be noted that when you import a set of data that is not already in the database, you need to comment the import transform out so that the key will be auto-created.